# Problems with Ubuntu mount /tmp

Tags: 14.04

Problems with ubuntu
**apt-get install -f**

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I tried mount back the tmp but it doesnts works
Someone know How to fix it?

```
root@pipoca:/var/tmp# mount /tmp
mount: can't find /tmp in /etc/fstab

root@pipoca:/var/tmp# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3008         868        1327          13         812        1964
Swap:           263           0         263

root@pipoca:/tmp# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           301M  4.5M  297M   2% /run
/dev/vda1        25G   25G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.5G  8.0K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           301M     0  301M   0% /run/user/0



    root@pipoca:/# dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
dpkg-query: no packages found matching linux-*
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

using

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

I got

```
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
```

using

```
root@pipoca:/# sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=2d
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals on disk.
root@pipoca:/# journalctl --vacuum-size=500M
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals on disk.

root@pipoca:/# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-universal InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
not a reference at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 222.
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: As `apt` needs some space to run, first delete some files, then run `apt`

Comment: Use `uname -r` to get the release # of the current kernel. Delete NO file/dir with this string as part of its name. Look for (with `ls -l`) old files in `/var/log/`, `/boot/`, `/home/$USER` and delete them manually. Then `sudo apt autoremove`. This is why many people have separate partitions for `/`, `/home', `/boot`.

Answer (score 4):

**Your hard drive is full.**

As `df` does not show any other empty space, you will need to delete something.

First remove not needed data from your `/home`, e.g. you could move Pictures, Videos and Music to an external drive or remove them you don't need anymore. Remove files in `~/.thumbnails` folder. You might use `bleachbit` to gain more space (it tries to delete cached files, etc.).

After that, try:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

But all **this is just a temporary solution**, 25G is just very little space for OS and data.

I see two possibilities:

- Install less programs and keep less data on your drive.

or

- Install a second hard drive for `/home`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to delete some files anywhere under `/`.  Your `df -h` output shows that is full.

You might find `du` (disk usage) helpful in seeing what specific directories have a lot of data, maybe more than expected.

Often `/var/log` and `~/Downloads` accumulate a lot of unnecessary data.

Sometimes `journalctl` - the systemd log facility, uses a lot of memory unexpectedly.  The amount it uses [can be controlled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139513/how-to-clear-journalctl):

Retain only the past two days:

```
sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=2d
```

Retain only the past 500 MB:

```
journalctl --vacuum-size=500M
```